# Align content of table cells differently

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in which a row's first cell (`td`) contains padding. Now the issue is with the second cell in that row, it somehow inherits the padding from the previous cell, which is not what I want

```css
td{
  border:3px solid black;
}
.a>span {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.b {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"><span>Bar foo</span></td>
    <td class="b">Bar foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

So the question is: how can I align the text in the second cell to the top?

Comment: but your code works?

Comment: If I press the blue 'Run code snippet' button, it works as you want it to. Do you see this button? Check any other CSS that might cause your problem.

Comment: I just now checked in chrome and the second cell text is already aligned in the top.May I know which browser you are checking?

Comment: Ok in Fx, Chr and Edge on Win10

Comment: works fine on the code-snippet, you must have some CSS somewhere else changing it

Comment: For me too it's working fine (chrome Version 54.0.2840.98)

Comment: you can add padding:0 !important;vertical-align: top !important; to override any CSS, but it's not recommended.

Comment: it was indeed a reset on `td` with `vertical-align: baseline` which cased this issue. Thanks for the help!